# Are American census bags recyclable?

Tags: recycling, plastic, usa

Yesterday, I received my census questionnaire. So have many millions of other Americans, recently.

These bags are not labeled for recycling, but are they recyclable? Can I put them in the deposits at my local grocery store with other bags marked "4?"

(Allow me to officially protest manufacturers of plastic that don't label them for recycling)